# How to supress multiple alerts and receive only one notification in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I'm looking for a way to create a Zabbix monitor that will only alert when we have a bunch of other alerts on board.
For example, I have created alerts A, B, C, and so on, and when they appear separately, it is not a big deal, but if together, I would like to know and receive a notification to act accordingly.

Therefore, I wonder if it's feasible to design an alert D that only appears when all the others do.

I have only found a solution using dependent triggers, but it's not suitable in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

If the items are in the same host, just add a higher severity trigger when all items breach their threshold.

If the items are in different hosts, you can add a "parent" host, with the metrics you need. Example: in a 8 nodes cluster, each cluster node will have a Warning severity problem when it's offline, and the parent host will have a High severity problem when more than 4 nodes are offline.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. How to create such a trigger and force it to alert only if more than 4 nodes are down?
If using the dependent trigger, it would be convenient if I have 8 nodes in cluster but what if I have much more

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Trigger Dependency. You can update the current trigger and add dependency with other triggers.

In this case your trigger gets suppressed if the depended triggered is already fired.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new trigger in the host. That trigger has A, B and C problem expressions with 'and' without quotation marks in between them. So:

```
{itemA}.last()>1
```

(or whatever logic you need for the trigger)

and

```
{itemB}.last()>1
```

and

```
{itemC}.last()>1
```

And in the original triggers put dependency for the new trigger.

I'd suggest to put the problem expression a bit tighter in the new trigger so that will fire up before the original singular triggers. And recovery expression a bit longer so the regular triggers can resolve before the new trigger.